# How to run python code from linux via a docker containing a specific python version

Tags: python, linux, docker, server

I have a linux server running in which I want to be able to run some python scripts. To do so, I created a docker image of python (3.6.8) with some specific dependencies to run my code.

I am new to linux command line and need help on how to write a line that would run a given python script based on my docker (python 3.6.8)

My server's directory structure looks like this :

[image: Server structure]

My docker is named geomatique_python and its image is located in docker_image.

As for the structure of the code itself, I am starting from scratch and am looking for some hints and advices.

Thanks

Comment: It will be vastly easier to avoid Docker and just install Python on your host, in the unusual event you don’t already have it.

Comment: Why are you using Docker - Would a virtual env work for you?

Comment: Long story short, I know this is not a typical use case of Docker, but I rely on some specific version of a few libraries that I need to set in stone, hence the docker containing only Python and some specific versions of a few libraries.

Comment: @DavidMaze I disagree, `docker` for everything, made my life easier especially in terms of version management, e.g. swapped `virtualenv` / `virtualenvwrapper` with `docker` and never looked back. Managing multiple versions of anything on an OS can become a pain (`PATH` settings, etc). @OP, is a typical use-case for me, really depends on who you ask and what that person's experience with `docker` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very much for a *all the things* in `docker` approach. Ref. your mention of having specific versions set in stone, the declaritive nature of `docker` is great for that. You can extend an official `python` `docker` image with your libraries then bind-mount the folders into your container during the run. A minimal project might look like:

```
.
├── app.py
└── Dockerfile
```

My `app.py` is a simple requests script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                                                                                                  

import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com')

if r.status_code == 200:
    print("HTTP {}".format(r.status_code))
```

My `Dockerfile` contains the runtime dependencies for my app:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

RUN python3 -m pip install requests
```

**Note**: I'm extending the [official python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) image in this example.

After building the `docker` image (i.e. `docker build --rm -t so:57697538 .`) you can run a container from the image bind-mounting the directory that contains the scripts inside the container and execute them: `docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/src --entrypoint python3 so:57697538 /src/app.py`

Admittedly for `python` `virtualenv` / `virtualenvwrapper` can be convenient however it's very much `python`-only whereas `docker` is language agnostic.

Comment: Thats very clear. I'll give it a try. Thank you masseyb.